# Why is the output out of order?

Tags: rust

When running

```rust
#![allow(unused)] // For beginning only.

use std::fs::read_dir;
use std::io::{BufWriter, stdout};

use ferris_says::say;

use crate::prolog::*;

mod error;
mod prolog;
mod utils;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let stdout = stdout();
    let message = String::from("Hello fellow Rustaceans!");
    let width = message.chars().count();

    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(stdout.lock());
    say(&message, width, &mut writer).unwrap();

    for entry in read_dir("./")?.filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {
        let entry: String = W(&entry).try_into()?;
        println!("{entry}");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

the output is

```
/Users/eric.kolotyluk/.cargo/bin/cargo run --color=always --package hello-rust --bin hello-rust
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/hello-rust`
./Cargo.toml
./target
./Cargo.lock
./.gitignore
./hello-rust.iml
./.git
./.idea
./src
 __________________________
< Hello fellow Rustaceans! >
 --------------------------
        \
         \
            _~^~^~_
        \) /  o o  \ (/
          '_   -   _'
          / '-----' \

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As someone new to Rust, very new, I cannot see any obvious reason the output from `say` comes last.

**Why does `say` come last?**

Does it have something to do with `unwrap`?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. a full snippet which we can copy and run.

Comment: FYI, stdout is already buffered, so putting it in a `BufWriter` is pure overhead.

Comment: The way you're creating a `String` just to pass a reference to it to `say` tells me you might have used `&String` instead of `&str` for it's argument type which you [should almost never do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/442760)

Comment: The full project can be found at https://github.com/kolotyluk/hello-rust

Answer (score 2):

If you apply @pitaj's suggestion, and replace:

```rust
let mut writer = BufWriter::new(stdout.lock());
```

With:

```rust
let mut writer = stdout.lock();
```

Then your issue is immediately resolved. Why? You likely have a misconception about when `BufWriter` actually flushes.

1. [`stdout` is line-buffered](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.print.html), i.e. it flushes on `\n`
2. whereas [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html) has a (default) [8 KiB capacity](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html#method.new), so you likely won't trigger a flush using `say()`

So the reason you're seeing the output of `say()` after. Is because when the [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html) is dropped, then it is implicitly flushed.

If you want to ensure the output of `say()` is flushed earlier, then you need to manually call `writer.flush()`:

```rust
...
say(&message, width, &mut writer).unwrap();

writer.flush()?;

for entry in read_dir("./")?.filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {
    ...
```

Additionally, note that while `BufWriter` flushes on drop, it is recommended to [flush before dropping](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html) to catch any potential errors. As otherwise any flushing errors are silently ignored.

```rust
for entry in read_dir("./")?.filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {
    ...
}

writer.flush()?;

Ok(())
```

Comment: Also worth noting that `stdout.lock` uses a reentrant `Mutex`, which explains why the code doesn't deadlock when attempting to `println` while the `BufWriter` still holds the lock: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/io/stdio.rs.html#570

Comment: Thanks @vallentin that indeed works. I am just learning based on other people's examples, so none of the code is mine, just fragments from other people pieced together; so I have a lot of misconceptions at the moment.

Comment: @EricKolotyluk That is of course totally fine, that's why we're all helping each other :)

Comment: In 1995 I thought Java was pretty magic, after shooting myself in the foot constantly with C++. In 2024, I am learning that Rust is a different kind of magic. It's kind of an ugly duckling at times, but I am sure there is a beautiful swan somewhere...

Comment: @EricKolotyluk For some reason people (initially) see Rust as "ugly". I've always seen Rust (syntax) as a child of OCaml, C and Python. As someone who's read absolutely cursed C and C++ code, then I think Rust is super easy to read. The fact that you can look at a (mutable) references, and just know than nothing (else) is invalidating them is so nice. In C++ the [iterator invalidation rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Iterator_invalidation) has always been the bane of my existence, because they sometimes weren't true nor consistent across implementations

Comment: Before C++ I was comfortable with C, and after C++ I thought it was better than C. But when I started using Java, I turned my back on C++ as toxic. I am now proficient in Java, Scala, and Kotlin. I have to admit Rust is growing on me, hence the swan comment, but there are a lot new habits to integrate. The more I learn, the more deep wisdom I discover.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand things better, another solution I found was

```
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let stdout = stdout();
    let message = String::from("Hello fellow Rustaceans!");
    let width = message.chars().count();

    {
        let mut writer = BufWriter::new(stdout.lock());
        say(&message, width, &mut writer).unwrap();
    }

    for entry in read_dir("./")?.filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {
        let entry: String = W(&entry).try_into()?;
        println!("{entry}");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```